# Как искать видео?

Tags: api, twitter, twitter-api

Есть метод https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search 
Я хочу найти видео. Как это сделать? (какой запрос)

Answer (score 1):

```
$api = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$query = 'видео курсы';
$url = $api . '?q=' . rawurlencode($query . ' filter:native_video');
```